# WSO2 - Best way to implement ETL jobs

Tags: wso2, etl, wso2-enterprise-integrator

What is the best way to implement ETL jobs using WSO2.
We've been trying to leverage data services within WSO2 EI 6.4.

Our objective is to fetch data from web services as well as RDBMS and to store it to an RDBMS.

Any suggestions / ideas will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In My Experience with WSO2 middleware, Data services may not be the best fit for ETL jobs.
We had similar case where we wanted to copy data from one Databse to another Application.
For that we wrote integration (java) web service to fetch data from database send to the applciation using application Interface (web service exposed from application). and configured the Integration web service in EI scheduler to periodically run the service to sync the data.

Comment: I had came across some forums where it is mentioned about WSO2 Stream Processor used for ETL activities.

We are trying to stick with features / modules provided by WSO2 itself. What difference you found in using data services vs java web service ?

Comment: @Renju *Data Services* represent a simple way to expose data as service -you can define simple soap or rest services to retrieve or manipulate data in the underlaying datastore (rdbms mostly). Though don't expect any logic or proactive activity itself. If you need any logic or processing, you need to use something else. IMHO using WSO2SP for ETL is an interesting approach, through it may or may not be feasible for every use case, needs to be validated

Comment: Thank you everyone for your thoughts and suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Stream processor is better but need to really see if it fits in for ETL